# Ant wsdl2java to Maven wsdl2java convertion

Tags: maven, wsdl2java

I am trying to convert building my project from Ant to Maven.

I have a wsdl by name TestServiceWSDL_TestServiceV1Http_Service.wsdl in my project.

When I use Ant build (axis-wsdl2java), it generates the classes as below:

```
TestServiceWSDL_TestServiceV1HttpBindingStub.java
TestServiceWSDL_TestServiceV1HttpService.java
TestServiceWSDL_TestServiceV1HttpServiceLocator.java
```

When I convert it to Maven, I see that it generates the classes as below.

```
TestServiceV1_TestServiceWSDLTestServiceV1HttpPort_Client.java
TestServiceV1_TestServiceWSDLTestServiceV1HttpPort_Server.java
TestServiceWSDLTestServiceV1HttpService.java
```

How do I convert my project to use Maven build and generate the classes with same names?

Ant command used:

```
<target name="wsdl2java">
    <axis-wsdl2java output="${gen.dir}" testcase="false" verbose="false" url="wsdl.url">
        <mapping namespace="namespace.from.wsdl.1" package="package.1" />
        <mapping namespace="namespace.from.wsdl.2" package="package.2" />
    </axis-wsdl2java>
</target>
```

Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>ws/TestServiceWSDL_TestServiceV1Http_Service.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>namespace.1=package.1</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>namespace.2=package.2</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <defaultOptions>
            <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
        </defaultOptions>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <args>
            <arg>-npa</arg>
        </args>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution using cxf-codegen-plugin, but have resolved it now using:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <tasks>
                    <taskdef resource="axis-tasks.properties" classpathref="maven.compile.classpath" />
                    <mkdir dir="target/generated/src/main/java" />
                    <axis-wsdl2java output="target/generated/src/main/java" testcase="false"
                        verbose="false"
                        url="ws/TestServiceLookupWSDL_TestServiceLookupV1Http_Service.wsdl">
                        <mapping namespace="namespace.1"
                            package="package.1" />
                        <mapping namespace="namespace.2"
                            package="package.2" />
                    </axis-wsdl2java>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```